# Cannot iterate over "dataList" returned from service call to java backend in angular 9 application

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular9

I have some json data that is returned from a java backend service (houseguidelines) as a dataList via a service call from an angular application to that same application. I am trying to iterate over the json data that is returned and push it on to an array I created. However, I cannot accomplish this as I keep getting "undefined" errors in the browser console when I attempt this.

The service call in the angular application looks like this:

```
export class HouseGuidelinesService {
   private readonly houseGuidelinesURL = 'http://localhost8200/homeguidelines';

   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   getHouseData(houseCode: string): Observable<HouseGuidelineResponse[]> {
   
   return this.http.get<HouseGuidelineResponse[]>(this.houseGuidelinesURL + '/', {headers: {houseCodeList: houseCode}});    
}
}
```

The file that sends the data to the service call in the angular application looks something like this:

```
export class HouseComponent implements OnInIt {

houseData: HouseGuidelineResponse[];
houseList = [];

constructor(private: activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private houseSummaryService: HouseService, private houseGuidelinesService: HouseGuidelinesService ) {}

callHouseService(houseCodeList) {
  this.houseGuidelinesService.getHouseData(houseCodeList).subscribe(
  (data) => {
  this.houseData = data;
  console.log('display house guidelines', this.houseData);
  console.log('first house data: ', this.houseData[0])
  },
  (error) => {
  console.log('Error Getting House Policy Info!');
  }
  );


}
}
```

The value object for HouseGuidelineResponse in the angular application looks like this:

```
export class HouseGuidelineResponse {
id: number;
name: string;
description: string;
settings: HouseSettings[];
}
```

The service call works and returns data as json that looks like this in the browser console:

```
dataList: Array(3)
  0: {id:1, name: 'house risk 1', description: 'the best guidelines', settings: Array(1)}
  1: {id:2, name: 'house risk 2', description: 'the next best guidelines', settings: Array(1)}
  2: {id:3, name: 'house risk 3', description: 'the worst guidelines', settings: Array(1)}
```

The problem comes in when I try to iterate or access any of the data from the data list, I cannot. For example, in the callHouseService(houseCodeList) function, I do something like:

```
for (const value of this.houseData) {
 this.houseList.push({
 id: value.id
})
}

console.log(this.houseList)
```

I get an error stating "houseData is not iterable".

Alternatively, when I try to access individual elements of the "dataList" I am told they are undefined. For example, the following code below shows as "undefined" in the browser console. With the last console.log statement also giving this error as well "error typeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'description')."

```
console.log('first element: ', this.houseData[0]);
console.log('maybe the first element: ', this.houseData[0].description);
```

My question is, how do I properly iterate over the returned json "dataList" to gain access to the json so I can use it and then assign it to my created value object?

Comment: Hi, may I know where you place the `for` loop. Is it in the `.subscribe()`? Or can you place the complete code on how you call `this.houseData` for debugging purpose? Thanks.

Comment: @YongShun inside the `subscribe`. Also, all the code above is where / how I call `this.houseData`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the result of `console.log('display house guidelines', this.houseData);` which is attached in the question, I believe your response data is looked as below:

```
{
  "dataList": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "house risk 17",
      "description": "the best guidelines",
      "settings": [...]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "house risk 2",
      "description": "the next best guidelines",
      "settings": [...]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "house risk 3",
      "description": "the worst guidelines",
      "settings": [...]
    }
  ]
}
```

---

As your `getHouseData` method returns value of `Observable<HouseGuidelineResponse[]>`, you can add `.pipe()` with `map` rxjs operator to return `response.dataList` for `Observable`.

> .service.ts

```js
getHouseData(houseCode: string): Observable<HouseGuidelineResponse[]> {
   return this.http
     .get<HouseGuidelineResponse[]>(this.houseGuidelinesURL + '/', {
       headers: { houseCodeList: houseCode },
     })
     .pipe(map((response: any) => response.dataList));
}
```

[Sample Demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zz5puw?file=src/app/services/house-guidelines.service.ts)